# Dapper, list of parameters, possible memory issues

Tags: parameters, dapper

I'm using dapper and solr. After I get ids from solr I'm quering db like that:

```
var dbResults = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Product>(@"SELECT  p.[ProductId] as Id]
                                                                        ,p.[Product] as [Name]
                                                                        ,p.[Price]
                                                                        ,p.[SeoLink]                                                                            
                                                                        ,p.[CategoryId]                                   
                                                            FROM [dbo].[Products] p with(nolock)                                                                
                                                            WHERE p.[ProductId] in @productsIds", new {productsIds = toGet}, commandTimeout: 2);
```

Count of ids is changing from 1 to 200. Will I have memory issues because every query will be cached separately? Any ideas how can I optimize it? (I'm using azure website with sql azure and I'm getting 500 internal server error from time to time without any reason, nothing in logs.)

Comment: Are you sure the 500 is coming from a memory issue? Did you profile your application and the server?

Comment: This is azure web site so I don't have access to server logs only to application log (event log). I can't see anything interesting there. Only some simple errors. I have custom errors "on" but in case of this 500 I see error page from iis not my application. I'm looking for solution and by accident saw possibility of memory issues for non parametrized queries. I "dot traced" my aplication on local machine but can't see anything really wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at the .NET side we only cache that once per text / connection-string pair, where "text" here is the fixed TSQL query before any voodoo. The *generated IL* for that scenario includes a call to `PackListParameters` (which is **after** all the cache steps etc - just before exec), which adds the multiple parameters and changes the TSQL.